# android untrue resource not found exception 

Tags: android, resources

I am not a new developer to android. I have an application on the market. However, sometimes I get reported strange exceptions to have occured:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-mdpi/background.png

 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-mdpi/background.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f02001f
```

This is by all means untrue because otherwise I wouldn;t have compiled or run the program myself. Also I am sure the resources are there. This is just one of the exception I have been reported. There are same exceptions for other resources mainly layouts.

So my question is how would this happen? Is it because the android system has failed installing correctly my app? I almost sure this must be the case because I have many users who use it without problem.

Please help regarding this.

Comment: It sometimes happen to us too with some layout resources. Although the situation is far from critical for us, it remained a mysterious bug. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Do you tested your app on all screen sizes and densities? Maybe the problem could be that on some screens the drawables were not found in the corresponding directory

Comment: @Cata You shouldn't need to make/populate drawable folders for every density. If, for example, you only provide xdpi drawables, an mdpi screen will scale down the drawables to draw correctly.

Comment: @Jonba that is correct though I've experienced some problems regarding this and that is why I suggested to check his drawable directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be several possible reasons:

1. Moving application to SD card.
2. There was some problem in downloading or installing APK from market (file can be corrupted).
3. User get APK with corrupted file from other source (for example via bluetooth from other user)
4. Some system bug (from software, to brocken hardware)

**Any way You can't do anything with this problem.**

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the application was pushed to SD Card and something happens to the drawable while on SD. I saw similar issues with layouts rather drawable and it was because the application was pushed to SD.

Comment: This is really a probable answer but unfortunately I cannot test this and say if it's for sure as it happens on rare cases. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have included certain codes that reference content from Android SDK.

In my case, I faced similar issue and when I removed the line

```
android:background="?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground"
```

from my xml, everything works fine again.